# Is it possible in linux to add two same flags in one command

Tags: linux, spring, bash, command, flags

Is it possible in linux to add two same flags in one command?
For example:

```
screen -c ./logs.conf -dmSL 'Server' java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=8080ssl -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2  ssl-springProject-0.0.11-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Is the proper way to be written for the flag -D? Or should it be linked something like '&'?

Comment: From Linux's POV, it is. But it's ultimately up to the specific program how to interpret the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. However, they cannot go between `-jar` and the jar file.

```
screen -c ./logs.conf -dmSL 'Server' java -Dspring.profiles.active=8080ssl \
        -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -jar ssl-springProject-0.0.11-SNAPSHOT.jar
```